# How to make App-to-Per-App VPN work on MAC OSX?

Tags: swift, networkextension

I'm attempting to learn more about the NEAppProxyProvider since I am trying to develop a mac OSX per app vpn.

What have been achieved is that the app proxy could be started and with SafariDomains setting the stream from Safari could be captured by handleNewFlow in AppProxyProvider. Now I'm trying to capture some other flow from specified apps with com.apple.vpn.managed.appmapping set in the profile. But after install the profile there is only one settings shown in Profiles. I've googled around trying to find an example or template of the profile but get nothing helpful. Please help me with checking the following profile to see if there are any problems in it.

Here's the profile which include two dicts in the array. The first dict  works with Safari flow. The second dict is for per-app vpn but it seems can not be installed correctly and does not work. The SafariDomains part has been removed since I learned from apple developer forums that SafariDomains can not work with app mapping together.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PayloadContent</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>IPv4</key>
            <dict>
                <key>OverridePrimary</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>PayloadDescription</key>
            <string>Configures VPN settings</string>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>VPN</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.vpn.managed.applayer.330FBB83-639F-4F9E-9FA1-4FAC93E18B68</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.vpn.managed.applayer</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>330FBB83-639F-4F9E-9FA1-4FAC93E18B68</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>Proxies</key>
            <dict>
                <key>HTTPEnable</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>HTTPSEnable</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>UserDefinedName</key>
            <string>appmapping</string>
            <key>VPN</key>
            <dict>
                <key>AuthName</key>
                <string>somebody</string>
                <key>AuthPassword</key>
                <string>opendoor</string>
                <key>AuthenticationMethod</key>
                <string>Password</string>
                <key>ProviderBundleIdentifier</key>
                <string>com.blob.macappproxy.macappproxy</string>
                <key>ProviderType</key>
                <string>app-proxy</string>
                <key>RemoteAddress</key>
                <string>127.0.0.1</string>
            </dict>
            <key>VPNSubType</key>
            <string>com.blob.macappproxy</string>
            <key>VPNType</key>
            <string>VPN</string>
            <key>OnDemandMatchAppEnabled</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>VendorConfig</key>
            <dict/>
            <key>VPNUUID</key>
            <string>3D7A07D8-97D0-4E5A-BB04-1EB82DD12A35</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>PayloadDescription</key>
            <string>Configures Per APP VPN mapping</string>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>Per APP VPN mapping</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.vpn.managed.appmapping.A88E1A77-2CC2-4BF9-879C-97C3DF491EB2</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.vpn.managed.appmapping</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>A88E1A77-2CC2-4BF9-879C-97C3DF491EB2</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>UserDefinedName</key>
            <string>perappvpn</string>
            <key>AppLayerVPNMapping</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>Identifier</key>
                    <string>com.google.Chrome</string>
                    <key>VPNUUID</key>
                    <string>3D7A07D8-97D0-4E5A-BB04-1EB82DD12A35</string>
                    <key>DesignatedRequirement</key>
                    <string>(identifier &quot;com.google.Chrome&quot; or identifier &quot;com.google.Chrome.beta&quot; or identifier &quot;com.google.Chrome.dev&quot; or identifier &quot;com.google.Chrome.canary&quot;) and certificate leaf = H&quot;c9a99324ca3fcb23dbcc36bd5fd4f9753305130a&quot;</string>
                    <key>SigningIdentifier</key>
                    <string>com.google.Chrome</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
    <string>some app proxy</string>
    <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
    <string>blob-MacBook-Pro.A953E629-CD95-45B4-A42D-ECA2BA870A79</string>
    <key>PayloadRemovalDisallowed</key>
    <false/>
    <key>PayloadType</key>
    <string>Configuration</string>
    <key>PayloadUUID</key>
    <string>1AEA709E-46D3-4293-B1E3-23EB8DD5B361</string>
    <key>PayloadVersion</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

How should it be modified to let the specified application's network flow be captured in appproxyprovider's handleNewFlow method? Or can someone please paste a workable profile?